# Define parameters to be used in a web page as an input

Tags: javascript, html, function, input, submit

I'm trying to submit two parameters to be used in a javascript function. The code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="proj4js/lib/proj4js/lib/proj4js-compressed.js"></script>

</head>
<body>


<script>
function func1 (x,y){

     var z=x+y
     alert(z)

    }                           

</script>
<form >
first input:<br>
<input type="text" y="Y" value=85>
<br>
second input:<br>
<input type="text" x="X" value=15>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<button type="button" onclick="func1(x,y)">Try it</button>
```

The error I get is `Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined` How should I define x and y as an input to be put in js function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/hmfcLsf2/1/

```
<body>
<script>
function func1 (x,y){
   var z=parseInt(x)+parseInt(y)
   alert(z)
}
</script>
<form >
first input:<br>
<input id="y_field" type="text" y="Y" value=85>
<br>
second input:<br>
 <input id="x_field" type="text" x="X" value=15>
<br><br>
</form>

<button type="button" onclick="func1(document.getElementById('x_field').value,document.getElementBy    Id('y_field').value)">Try it</button>
```

Use getElementById. See the jsfiddle above.

Comment: Thanks a lot, can you tell me how to put the answer in another textbox ?

Comment: Sorry for taking too long. If you are still looking to put the answer in another textbox add another textbox like <input id="x_result" type="text"> and then in the function instead of alert(z), use this document.getElementById('x_result').value = z

Answer (score 1):

In the scope the button doesn´t exist the attritubes X and Y. You need to take the element input and access to attr X or Y:

```
*<form >
first input:<br>
<input type="text" y="Y" value=85>
<br>
second input:<br>
<input id="id-x" type="text" x="X" value=15>
<br><br>
<input id="id-y" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<button type="button" onclick="func1(document.getElementById('id-x').x, document.getElementById('id-y').y)">Try it</button>*
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the error message is clear: you must define variables if you want to use them. Javascript engine doesn't know what `x` and `y` should be in your case.

So you need to select input element first and then take its value. How to select element? You need to identify it somehow. For example by giving it an id:

```
<input type="text" id="Y" value=85>
<input type="text" id="X" value=15>
```

I replaced meaningless `x`, `y` attributes with id. Then ugly usage would be:

```
<button type="button" onclick="func1(Number(document.querySelector('#X').value), Number(document.querySelector('#Y').value))">Try it</button>
```

Of course this is not very convenient to use. There is more modern way to bind event handlers, using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method. Again, give the button some id:

```
<button type="button" id="button">Try it</button>
```

And then all together it will become:

```html
<form>
    first input:<br>
    <input type="text" id="Y" value=85> <br>
    
    second input:<br>
    <input type="text" id="X" value=15>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<button type="button" id="button">Try it</button> 


<script>
document.querySelector('#button').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var x = Number(document.querySelector('#X').value),
        y = Numberdocument.querySelector('#Y').value);
  
    func1(x, y);
});
  
function func1 (x, y) {
     var z = x + y;
     alert(z);
}
</script>
```

One more important note. You need to pass numbers to `func1` function, otherwise `+` operator will behave weird. The problem here is that input elements value is always a `String` (numeric string in your case), and `+` acts like concatenation operator if used with strings. So you need to explicitly cats string to number, for example with `Number` function.

Answer (score 1):

Add `id` to `<input>`s, and convert their `.value` into number:

```js
function func1 (x,y){

     var z=(+x)+(+y);
     alert(z);

}
```

```html
<form >
first input:<br>
<input type="text" id="Y" name="Y" value=85>
<br>
second input:<br>
<input type="text" id="X" name="X" value=15>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<button type="button" onclick="func1(document.getElementById('X').value,document.getElementById('Y').value)">Try it</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to change anything in your markup, you could simply axtract the values with `document.querySelector` :

```js
function callFunc() {
    func1(parseInt(document.querySelector('[y="Y"]').value), 
          parseInt(document.querySelector('[x="X"]').value));
}
```

call `callFunc()` instead :

```html
<button type="button" onclick="callFunc();">Try it</button>
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/s2z13q14/**